# How to create a Lightning Web Component using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to design a Lightning web component in Visual Studio 2015 and not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: [This](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components) trailhead will be the best place to start with Lightning Web Components.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's not possible, searching on the marketplace of Microsoft i haven't found anything about salesforce developing. i've only found data integration with SF using Visual Studio.